# How to set redis list values atomically?

Tags: redis, atomic

I'd like to atomically set **all values** of a list, just like the regular `SET` command.

I need it because the list is to be a cached representation of a database query. I'd like to access the cache in the "paginated" mode by using `LRANGE`.

I thought of using [RPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpush/), but if a race condition occurs, my cache will contain multiple sets of duplicate results one after another, and I wouldn't like that.

Using `RPUSH` in conjunction with [LTRIM](https://redis.io/commands/ltrim/) to the known list length should work most of the time, but it may fail in cases where the data source returned different result sets and we had a race condition on `LTRIM`. Of course it's a lot less likely to happen, but still.

The `SORTED SET` with indexes as weights suffers from similar kinds of problems.

Using redis' transactions seems like an overkill: as far as I'm concerned, they halt all other incoming commands until the transaction is over -- and the cached result set may be a chunky one.

Yet, `DEL` and `RPUSH` in a transaction seems like the only option so far. Is it really?

Comment: Redis transactions do not halt all other incoming commands for Redis, merely for that connection. Usually you want to use a dedicated connection for transactions.

Comment: @GuyRoyse are you sure? I prematurely liked your comment, but I didn't find any confirmation of your words in the docs. The way it seems to work is: once you `EXEC`, no other command will come in between -- no matter the connection. Link: https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/

Comment: I am positive on my understanding of MUTIL and EXEC but not that my comment above does it justice. ;) When you call MULTI, the connection you do it on starts queueing commands. When you call EXEC, it executes all those commands atomically on the single thread that is at the core of Redis.

Comment: @GuyRoyse Your claim seems to contradict the first lines of [the redis official docs on transactions](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/): All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. **A request sent by another client will never be served in the middle of the execution of a Redis Transaction.** This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.

Comment: Emphasis on the word *execution*, which is what happens when EXEC is called. If it didn't work that way then the WATCH command would be pointless. The entire point of WATCH is that you call it before you call MULTI. If another connection then changes the watched key, the transaction will fail when you call EXEC. If you couldn't send any commands on Redis after a call to MULTI then WATCH wouldn't need to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it sounds like a transaction would generally be the easiest way to handle this:

```
MULTI
DEL list
RPUSH list item1 item2 item3...
EXEC
```

However, if your list is enormous, and you are concerned with blocking the Redis server while it's being populated, your other option would be to use a distributed locking pattern like [redlock](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/#the-redlock-algorithm) to lock the key from reads/writes while you populate the list.

Comment: I ended up doing just that: the transaction. Thank you. I wanted to go the lua scripting way, but it does not make a difference: it's the same as a transaction, with the only exception of it being more flexible (you can do anything `lua` can: read data and change the control flow, while transaction is write-only, no reads in between).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think I figured it out. It should be a LUA script, since they are atomic:

```
redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
local res = redis.call('LPUSH', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))
return res
```

I haven't tested it yet, but should work. First we delete the array, then we set all its values.

Answer (score 0):

LPUSH and RPUSH is variadic so you can just call either of them with all the values you want to add.

```bash
> RPUSH foo alfa bravo charlie delta
```

This will happen atomically.

Comment: Never mind,  I see you are doing that. ;)

Comment: It's actually about the race condition on the RPUSH. Imagine two processes experiencing a cache miss. They both go to the database, both receive some result set and write it into redis with `RPUSH`. What happens is: you end up with two OR more copies of the same data within your list, in case there is a race condition.